# Image link issues after importing a database backup to my local web server

Tags: database, installation, migration, options, local-installation

I am pretty new in WP (I came from Joomla) and I have the following problem trying to import an old WP blog (made using WP 3.5) on my local web server.

I have put the old blog foder into my **www** Apache directory and then I have imported the database on my local MySql DB.

After, I went into the **wp_options** DB table and I have change the value of the **option_value** field related to the rows **home** and **siteurl** putting in them the correct address (on my localhost web server)

Ok, it's seem to work fine: I can see my website and the articles on it but now I have the following problem:

if an article contain an immage I can't see this immage and if I open it in the browser appear to me the following error message: **404 Not Found**

```
Not Found

The requested URL "/it/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Andrea-Alfieri-chef-bassa3.jpg" was not found on this server.
```

And in the browser address bar I have the following **wrong URL**:

```
http://www.myOldWebSite.it/it/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Andrea-Alfieri-chef-bassa3.jpg
```

It is wrong because it is related to the old website URL and not to my localhost website.

I think that must be some wrong settings on my database and that I have to change it but I don't know what I have to change

Can you help me? Some ideas?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

WP uses the GUID column of posts for links.

You need to replace that, I use a script http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Just drop it in your root dir then follow the instructions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will try the script but before try it I want know what exactly is a GUID colums? Is it into a specific table or is it in more then a single tabes? Why have I to use a script? (if it is only in one table why don't change manually this value?)

Comment: You could do it manually, the guid is what wordpress uses to generate links for menus, posts, attachments (so only the post table) CODEX link: [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note)